# System font thin shown in Interfacebuilder but not on iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, fonts, interface-builder

I want some labels to have the thin style font. For this I use the system font thin or ultraligth. In Interfacebuilder it looks exactly how I want it to look. But starting the App on Simulator or iPad the labels font doesn't change, it is still the systems basic font.
Anyone an idea?

Comment: Make sure you have not set fonts programmatically anywhere.

Comment: This label doesn't have any outlet, or do you mean it could be set anywhere for global

Comment: No, I meant if it had outlet, then there could be a possibility that fonts were set from code and so IB was not reflected. Since it doesn't have outlet, it should work as you are expecting.

Comment: The label sure doesn't have an Outlet, I really don't know what to check next or how to find out why the thin font isn't shown on iPad like it looks on the simulator.

Comment: Do you have any font style stored in your project?

Comment: Yes I have, but for the label i use the System font

Answer (score 0):

Solved this problem. The labels had all a custom class. So if you make changes on Interface Builder it seems first that your App would take the uifont you have choosen on Interface Builder because the label appears immediately with the correct font , but in fact it takes its customClass.